# Remove repeat values from a dictionary 'a' in a dictionary 'b' python

Tags: python, dictionary

```
dictionary = {'0': "Linda", "1": "Anna", "2": 'Theda', "3":'Thelma',"4": 'Thursa',"5" :"Mary"}
dictionary2 = ['Linda', 'Ula', 'Vannie', 'Vertie', 'Mary']
```

I want to remove the same values from dictionary to dictionary2, I wrote the code like this:

```
[k for k, v in dictionary.items() if v not in dictionarya]
```

But it still can print out the words above same words, like this:

```
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']
```

How to remove all the repeat words? so it can print out like this: e,g.

```
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

How to just get the last loop? Thank you

Comment: What does "But it still can print out the words above same words" mean?

Answer (score 3):

To get the keys in which the values aren't contained in the other `list` you can use the following list comprehension

```
>>> [k for k,v in dictionary.items() if v not in dictionary2]
['2', '4', '3', '1']
```

Comment: If using Py3, doing `list(dictionary.values())` may be more efficient

Comment: @CoryKramer Thank you, I am sorry for that I wrote something wrong... I want to get the items from the first dictionary.

Comment: @CoryKramer Thank you, I used this code ... but it still can print out repeat words... like this :['Linda','Anna', 'Theda', 'Thelma','Thursa'] How to remove all the repeat words?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Where are you getting that list from? I showed you above what the output of my code shows. Do you want the list of words or numbers?

Comment: @CoryKramer Thank you for your response, I want to get the list of numbers, I still can get the repeat items by using this code.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following list comprehension:

```
>>> dictionary = {'0': "Linda", "1": "Anna", "2":"Mary"}
>>> dictionary2 = ['Linda', 'Theda', 'Thelma', 'Thursa', 'Ula', 'Vannie', 'Vertie', 'Mary']
>>> value = [i for i in dictionary2 if i not in dictionary.values()]
>>> value
['Theda', 'Thelma', 'Thursa', 'Ula', 'Vannie', 'Vertie']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
dictionary = {'0': "Linda", "1": "Anna", "2":"Mary"}
dictionary2 = ['Linda', 'Theda', 'Thelma', 'Thursa', 'Ula', 'Vannie', 'Vertie', 'Mary']
# I want to remove the same values from dictionary to dictionary2, I wrote the code like this:
output = [i for i in dictionary2 if i not in dictionary.values()]
```

Result:

```
['Theda', 'Thelma', 'Thursa', 'Ula', 'Vannie', 'Vertie']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert `dictionary2` to a set, and use this syntax:

```
>>> dictionary = {'0': "Linda", "1": "Anna", "2": 'Theda', "3":'Thelma',"4": 'Thursa',"5" :"Mary"}
>>> dictionary2 = ['Linda', 'Ula', 'Vannie', 'Vertie', 'Mary']
>>> remove_names = set(dictionary2)
>>> [name for name in dictionary.values() if name not in remove_names]
['Anna', 'Theda', 'Thelma', 'Thursa']
>>> [id for id, name in dictionary.items() if name not in remove_names]
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Note that `dictionary2` isn't a dict but a list.

Also, Python dicts are unordered. You cannot be sure that the result will always be `1,2,3,4`.

Finally, if all your dict keys are integers (or look like integers), you'd better use a list :

```
>>> names = ["Linda","Anna",'Theda','Thelma','Thursa',"Mary"]
>>> remove_names = set(['Linda', 'Ula', 'Vannie', 'Vertie', 'Mary'])
>>> list(enumerate(names))
[(0, 'Linda'), (1, 'Anna'), (2, 'Theda'), (3, 'Thelma'), (4, 'Thursa'), (5, 'Mary')]
>>> [name for name in names if name not in remove_names]
['Anna', 'Theda', 'Thelma', 'Thursa']
>>> [id for id, name in enumerate(names) if name not in remove_names]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This should be more readable and faster than your code.

Comment: Thank you, I tested the code of '[id for id, name in dictionary.items() if name not in remove_names]', but it can still print out the repeat words, how to remove all of them? Thank you

Comment: @BobbyZhao Do you want unique elements? Just convert the output list to a set : `set([1,1,2,3,3,4])` -> `set([1, 2, 3, 4])`

Answer (score 0):

```
dictionary = {'0': "Linda", "1": "Anna", "2":"Mary"}
dictionary2 = ['Linda', 'Theda', 'Thelma', 'Thursa', 'Ula','Vannie','Vertie', 'Mary']

for i in range(0, len(dictionary2)-1):
    if dictionary2[i] in dictionary.values():
        del dictionary2[i]

print (dictionary2)
```

Prints this:

```
['Theda', 'Thelma', 'Thursa', 'Ula', 'Vannie', 'Vertie']
```